# Changing the entire disposition of a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dataset

I have the following dataset

| Year | Gender | Freq |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2017 | F | 0.67 |
| 2017 | M | 0.32 |
| 2017 | Other | 0.01 |

**Desired output**

| Year | M | F | Other |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2017 | 0.32 | 0.67 | 0.01 |

I tried all the transposition codes i found but none of them gave me this result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `pivot_wider`

```
library(tidyr)
pivot_wider(df1, names_from = Gender, values_from = Freq)
```

Comment: It worked, thanks ! I'll accept your answer when Stack lets me !